# background position: fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have a little problem with fixed background in CSS. I need to fix it to the left corner.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5hhT.jpg

```
background: url('./images/coura.png') no-repeat fixed;
width: 451px;
height: 736px;
position: fixed;
background-attachment: left bottom;
```

Is there any way how to do it? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Do you care if the image gets cut off if the screen resolution is too small?

Comment: nope I care just about bigger resolutions. 1366x768 +

Comment: Just an FYI, `position` should be `left bottom` and `background-attachment` should be `fixed`. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to set the background position to `bottom left` like this:

`background: url('./images/coura.png') bottom left no-repeat fixed;`

Answer (score 1):

Your element needs to be where you want the background to be. Add `left: 0px; bottom: 0px;` to go with the fixed positioning.

Comment: I need it in the left corner down. If I do something like margin-top: whatever. I have problem in bigger resolution. live example -     **http://www.soutezime.org/pantheon/**

Comment: Well first of all why the heck is the height `1500px` on that "live example", and second where did I ever talk about `margin-top`?

Comment: Because if is height: 768px in bigger resolution You see just legs. I really dont know how to do it. So I am trying everything ;)

Comment: You're not making sense. A pixel size shows you the same amount of the image regardless of resolution...

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution would be to set the image as the `background-image` for your `body` and set the `background-attachment` property to `fixed`:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
body { background: url('./images/coura.png') 0 100% no-repeat fixed; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/FEskF/

Comment: But I need scroll-down this image with "like button" in it. So I think it can't be on the body background.